# Using Javascript to compare two input numbers in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am using Notepad++ to create a simple web page where a user types in two numbers into a text box, and then presses a button. When they press the button something comes up that tells them whether the first or second number is greater. I have the following code but cant get anything to come up.  Does anyone know whats wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Assignment 10 Form</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function greaterNum(){
        var value1;
        var value2;
        value1 = document.First_num.value;
        value2 = document.last_num.value;
        if (value1 > value2){
        alert('Value 1 is greater than value 2');
        document.body.style.background = "orange";
        }

    }


</script> 


<style type="text/css">
  body{background-color: #40FF00;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    }

#container{
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Assignment 10</h1>

<div id="container">
    <div class="Num">
    <form>
<label class="label1">Enter Value 1:</label>
<input type="text" name="First_num" value=" " />
<label class="label1">Enter Value 2:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_num" value=" " />
<br/>
<input type="button" value=" Which number is greater? " onclick="greaterNum();" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Values from inputs are retrieved as strings, you need to convert it to number. Try this:

```
value1 = +document.First_num.value;
value2 = +document.last_num.value;
```

Also, try to be consistent when naming your input, why caps for one and lowercase for the other?

Comment: @dewyze FYI, the ' .value' at the last is what completes the trick !

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use:

```
value1 = document.getElementById("First_num").value;
```

However, this **only** works if you assign the elements `id` attributes:

```
<input type="text" id="First_num" name="First_num" value=" " />
```

**Otherwise,** use the [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to floats.

```
value1 = parseFloat(document.First_num.value);
value2 = parseFloat(document.last_num.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Html is a string, not a value. You need to parse it in someway.

EDIT:

The problem seems to be grabbing the values, change it to getElementById and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/fHtZU/10/

HTML

```
<h1>Assignment 10</h1>

<div id="container">
    <div class="Num">
    <form>
<label class="label1">Enter Value 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="First_num" name="First_num" />
<label class="label1">Enter Value 2:</label>
<input type="text" id="last_num" name="last_num" />
<br/>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Which number is greater?" onclick="greaterNum()" />
</form>
```

js

```
function greaterNum(){
    var value1;
    var value2;
    value1 = document.getElementById("First_num").value;
    value2 = document.getElementById("last_num").value;
    if (value1 > value2){
        alert(value1 - value2);
        document.body.style.background = "orange";
    }

}
```

Comment: How do we parse this HTML?

Comment: I don't mean to be a downer, but in the future, please at least post the raw code for something and test on the local machine if possible. Thanks for the update!! :-)

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. There aren't always a lot of questions I really know how to answer, I got excited.

Comment: I would add that you need to check if the values entered by the user are numbers. You can use isNan function for that. You can do it using the function isNaN. 

if (isNaN(value1) || isNan(value2)) {
    alert('Enter numbers');
}