# jQuery decimal validation with random value not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to validate decimal number with random value from input box using jQuery?

I have sample code below:

```js
$("#actualWeight").on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var actualWeight = $("#actualWeight").val();
    var maxGrossWeight = "3.6";
    var minGrossWeight = "2.4";

    if (actualWeight > maxGrossWeight) {
      alert("More than max gross");
    } else if (actualWeight < minGrossWeight) {
      alert("Lower than min gross");
    } else {
      alert("Success");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="actualWeight" />
```

As you can see:
Min Gross = `2.4`
Max Gross = `3.6`

When I try to input `200`, it show me alert `Success` that should be show me alert `More than max gross`.

You can see it on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7fjksx2/1/)

Comment: When you read value from DOM, its read in string format. Try converting to numeric value. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7fjksx2/2/)

Comment: You're comparing string's, not numbers! You must to parsefloat value and set the var's maxGrossWeight and minGrossWeght without "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to compare two input numbers in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914514/using-javascript-to-compare-two-input-numbers-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is returning the value of input as string. Hence you are comparing string values.

You should set maxGrossWeight and minGrossWeght as float variable and parse the value of input element to float before doing the comparison :

```
 var actualWeight = parseFloat($("#actualWeight").val());
 var maxGrossWeight = 3.6;
 var minGrossWeight = 2.4;
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/63az01zo/)**