# JS operator on document.getElementById gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I am using this JS code without any issues:

```
if(document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value.length != '' &&
   document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value.length != '' && 
   document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value.length != '' && 
   document.getElementById('add_breedte').value.length != '') { 
 // do something }
```

I need to add one more check. When `add_calc_dia_out` is larger then `add_calc_dia_inner`

So I have changed the JS to:

```
if(document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value.length != '' && 
   document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value.length != '' && 
   document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value.length != '' && 
   document.getElementById('add_breedte').value.length != '' && 
  (document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value > document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value)) { 
 // do something }
```

But the code that should be triggered is not triggered. Also no errors are shown. What is the correct way to be sure that `add_calc_dia_out` is larger then `add_calc_dia_inner` ?

Comment: Form field values are strings. If your input is of numerical nature, convert the values to numbers first. `'9' > '11' == true`, `9 > 11 == false`.

Comment: Are the values integers?  If so, use `parseInt(...)`

Comment: Duplicate of [Using Javascript to compare two input numbers in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914514/using-javascript-to-compare-two-input-numbers-in-html)

Comment: `.value.length != ''` should be testing against 0  instead of empty string: `.value.length != 0` OR if you want: `.value.trim() != ''`

Comment: So `const srt_gew = +document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value.trim(), dia_inner = +document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value.trim(), 
dia_out =  +document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value.trim(), 
breedte = +document.getElementById('add_breedte').value.trim();
if (srt_gew && dia_inner && dia_out && breedte && dia_out > dia_inner) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compare 2 number in string. It will cause unexpected behavior like `'9'` > `'11'`. You have to `parseInt()` them first. Try this:

```
... && parseInt(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value) > parseInt(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value)) {
```

Also, you should check if it's a valid number or not before doing the compare:

```
!Number.isNaN(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value) && !Number.isNaN(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value))
```

Comment: This was already mentioned in the comments 15 minutes ago. No need for an answer here

Comment: DRY and empty string is not NaN

Comment: I know DRY but I dont want to rewrite that block of code so I just repeat them. Empty string should not pass the empty string check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a DRY version

```js
const num = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : +str;

const srt_gew = num(document.getElementById('add_calc_srt_gew').value),
    dia_inner = num(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_inner').value),
      dia_out = num(document.getElementById('add_calc_dia_out').value),
      breedte = num(document.getElementById('add_breedte').value);

if (srt_gew && dia_inner && dia_out && breedte && dia_out > dia_inner) { /* do something */ }
```